# 'of' as in "ask questions of somebody"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

I would like to ask about **of** in the following passage, which is the definition for **interrogate** on [Google's dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning%20of%20interrogate&rlz=1C1CHBF_koKR763KR763&oq=meaning%20of%20i&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57.3808j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

> ask questions **of** someone closely, aggressively, or formally.

I also looked up the definition for **of** but as the preposition is so versatile and has so many definitions that I have come to ask a question here.

In my theory, it can be equivalent to the following two possible interpretations.

1. ask (questions **of** someone) → ask questions **about** someone
2. (ask questions) **of** someone → ask questions **from** someone

Any explanations will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ask questions of someone is to direct questions at or to that person. Regarding your definition (2) - we don't "ask questions from" people.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :) But may I ask you a little more? I wonder if the way I used **from** is wrong. Maybe as an alternative preposition to **of**, is **at** more correct than **from** and is **at** actually usable in this case?

Comment: The way you used 'from' is wrong. To interrogate is to ask questions **of** someone. You cannot use **from** or **at**.